# require_login("publish_stream") doesn't working now 

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

because of this issue i cannot ask permission from user i want to publish a messgage to wall and news feed so how to do it using PHP

here is my code

$appapikey = "XXXXXXXXX";
$appsecret = "XXXXXXXXX";

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

$user_id = $facebook->require_login("publish_stream,offline_access");

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use facebook's new PHP SDK [From HERE](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)

and check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633413/prompting-permissions-on-facebook/4634014#4634014) this post for the authentication.I have posted the code for authentication in this post.Check it...